# How can I fetch Api without using setInterval?

Tags: reactjs

```
useEffect(() => {
    let clearData;
   
    
    clearData = setInterval(() => {
      axios.get(`getPlayersStats`,
        {
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-control-allow-origin': '*'
          },
          auth: {
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'password'
          },

        }).then(response => {
          // console.log("aa",response.data);
          setData(Object.values(response.data).flat());
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }, 20);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(clearData);
    }
  }, [])
```

This part of api is fetching the running time(data) but when i remove the setinterval it not working (update the time which is fetching from server)
using the setInterval run url many time in console there is XHR which is running continuously
there also more than 2 api which running the set Interval that take website load time more.
so how can i fetch the data without using the setInterval to update the value with every second?
want its needs than the data update

Comment: I doubt you want to make that API call every 20 milliseconds (shouldn't it be 1000 for one second?) With that said: this is polling and it's the way it is, do not forget to check if the component has been disposed inside your `then()` (and API call might be in-flight when the component has been unmounted). Nicer solutions exist, you might consider websockets (for example)

Answer (score -1):

use settimeout instead and also cleardata has to be outside the useeffect, use effect may runs more then once.

```js
const clearData = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  const fetch = () {
    axios.get(`getPlayersStats`, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-control-allow-origin': '*'
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      },

    }).then(response => {
      // console.log("aa",response.data);
      setData(Object.values(response.data).flat());
      clearData.current = setTimeout(fetch, 60);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  
  }
  fetch();
  return () => {
    clearInterval(clearData.current);
  }
}, [])
```